# SQL Query performance with if exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-performance, sqlperformance

I have this SQL query:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 RowId
               FROM   dbo.Cache AS C
               WHERE  StringSearched = @pcpnpi
                      AND colName = 'pcpnpi'
                      AND ModifiedAt > (SELECT ModifiedAt
                                        FROM   dbo.Patients AS p
                                        WHERE  P.RowID = C.RowID))
  BEGIN
      SELECT @constVal = FunctionWeight
      FROM   dbo.FunctionWeights
      WHERE  FunctionWeights.FunctionId = 33;

      INSERT INTO #Temp2
                  (RowNumber,ValFromUser,ColumnName,ValFromFunc,
                   FuncWeight,percentage)
      SELECT RowNumber,@pcpnpi,'pcpnpi',PercentMatch,
             @constVal,PercentMatch * @constVal
      FROM   dbo.Matchpcpnpi (@pcpnpi);
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO #Temp2
                  (RowNumber,ValFromUser,ColumnName,Percentage)
      SELECT RowId,StringSearched,ColName,PercentMatch
      FROM   dbo.Cache AS C
      WHERE  StringSearched = @pcpnpi
             AND colName = 'pcpnpi'
             AND ModifiedAt > (SELECT ModifiedAt
                               FROM   dbo.Patients AS p
                               WHERE  P.RowID = C.RowID)
  END
```

The above if statement is meant to avoid unnecessary look ups for strings that have already been searched earlier and `MatchPercent` has been calculated. In that case, it is directly retrieved from Cache table.

Above sql query is basically for one particular column and this same kind of query with just columnName and its value changing is repeated for many other columns in the procedure.

The `if Exists` check was obviously meant so that query performance could improve however the performance has gone down, probably because of extra checks.
Cache table which is actually meant to improve the performance, extra checks have ruined it. 
Is there a way to simplify above query,please ? Any directions on same will help.
Thanks

Comment: By the way: horrible syntax.

Comment: Have you considered deleting rows from cache when the data gets modified? That would reduce the I/O you'll be doing for the checking the time fields now. Also this seems to be at least 3rd question for the same thing for the last 24 hours, maybe you could update the original question...

Answer (score 2):

First insert into #temp2 based on exists condition. If the Insert record count is zero then do the another insert.  Try this.

```
INSERT INTO #Temp2
            (RowNumber,ValFromUser,ColumnName,Percentage)
SELECT RowId,StringSearched,ColName,PercentMatch
FROM   dbo.Cache AS C
WHERE  StringSearched = @pcpnpi
       AND colName = 'pcpnpi'
       AND ModifiedAt > (SELECT ModifiedAt
                         FROM   dbo.Patients AS p
                         WHERE  P.RowID = C.RowID)

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
  BEGIN
      SELECT @constVal = FunctionWeight
      FROM   dbo.FunctionWeights
      WHERE  FunctionWeights.FunctionId = 33;

      INSERT INTO #Temp2
                  (RowNumber,ValFromUser,ColumnName,ValFromFunc,
                   FuncWeight,percentage)
      SELECT RowNumber,@pcpnpi,'pcpnpi',PercentMatch,
             @constVal,PercentMatch * @constVal
      FROM   dbo.Matchpcpnpi (@pcpnpi)
  END
```

Answer (score 1):

First, consider this query in the `exists`:

```
select Top 1 RowId
from dbo.Cache as C
where StringSearched = @pcpnpi and
      colName = 'pcpnpi' and
      ModifiedAt > ( Select ModifiedAt FROM dbo.Patients p WHERE P.RowID = C.RowID))
```

For performance, you want indexes on `cache(StringSearched, colName, ModifiedAt, RowId)` and `Patients(RowId)`.

However, you are running this query twice.  I would suggest a structure more like:

```
declare @RowId . . . ;  -- I don't know the type

select Top 1 @RowId = RowId
from dbo.Cache as C
where StringSearched = @pcpnpi and
      colName = 'pcpnpi' and
      ModifiedAt > ( Select ModifiedAt FROM dbo.Patients p WHERE P.RowID = C.RowID));

if (@RowId) is null . ..
else . . .
```

Comment: Thank you. But could you specify if you are suggesting a clustered or a non clustered index on these column ?

Comment: @SImran . . . An index is non-clustered unless specified otherwise.  The clustered index is usually used for the primary key.